# sending negative int over serial

Tags: java, c++

For some project I have to send signed integers from Java over serial to a C++ program on a microcontroller. It works nicely for positive integers but the negative integers are wrapped around and show up as positive integers on the C++ side.

Here's the function that sends the int on the java side:

```
void writeIntToSerial(Serial port, int number) {
  port.write(byte(number << 24));
  port.write(byte(number << 16));
  port.write(byte(number << 8));
  port.write(byte(number << 0));
}
```

I do not just send the raw integer but some control characters before and after the payload. All this works fine.

The receiving (C++) side reads the input stream into a buffer array of char and then interprets the stream with a state machine depending on the control characters in the stream.

The part that converts the character stream back into an integer is a basic bitshift:

```
int startAngle = 0;
// [...]
startAngle = (payload[0] << 24) + (payload[1] << 16) + (payload[2] << 8) + payload[3];
```

As mentioned earlier it works just fine for positive values but i.e. a -60 will convert into 196 (256 - 60).

I realize the solution is probably trivial but I've been staring at this code for too long... I'm lost.

Comment: Is this your actual code? I'm having a hard time believing that the displayed code would work even for positive values.

Comment: It is. When posting this i accidentially pasted write**Float**ToSerial() instead of write**Int**ToSerial() on the Java side but that is corrected since. The code works fine (for positive int).

Comment: So what's the definition of `port.write()`? Clearly it takes an int parameter, but what does it do with it? Since you're shifting left, when trying to send the int `-1` it would first write `0xFF000000`, then `0xFFFF0000`, then `0xFFFFFF00` and finally `0xFFFFFFFF`. I can't imagine `write()` would use only the 8 most significant bits.

Comment: This is the Serial.write() from Processing: [doc here](https://www.processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/Serial_write_.html).

Comment: you're sending it the wrong way because you're sending 16 bytes `0x12000000 0x00340000 0x00005600 0x00000078` for a single `0x12345678` int value. You need to shift left and mask instead of right shift

Comment: I see what you mean but I'm sending/receiving 4 bytes for the int, not 16. The state machine that does the parsing of the input stream would throw an error if the byte count wouldn't add up

Answer (score 0):

It looks like on one end you are serializing an `float` and on the other end you are receiving an `int`. Because of the way these data types are stored internally there are bound to be some inconsistencies.

So either you send/receive a **float** or an **int**, but **don't mix them up**.

Comment: Yeah I just realized I pasted the wrong function. See the actual writeIntToSerial() in the OP now. Sry for that

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are summing them together so they will be sign extented to 32bit.

If you OR them together you should get correct results.

Comment: I just changed the receiving end to this

   startAngle = (payload[0] << 24) | (payload[1] << 16) | (payload[2] << 8) | payload[3];

with the same result. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

In your example when you send -60 you send the bytes

```
0000 0000
0000 0000
0000 0000
1100 0100
```

and then you reassemble it to

```
0...1100 0100
```

which is 196, so the code works just fine. If you would have sent a positive number greater than 255, you should also get bogus on the receiving end. It is because you are shifting in the *wrong direction* on the Java side.

Comment: One side of the communication is little endian, the other is big endian. This is why I send bytes in the receiving-sides byte order. This might be a dumb follow up question but if what you're saying would be right I wouldn't get, say, 60 when I send 60, correct?

Comment: you really should have a look at the functions `htonl` and `ntohl` - use them in your µC program and always convert into/from network byte order within your java app - this will ensure that your protocol is not OS-dependent / µC - dependent

Comment: If you shift a java int to the left for 8 or more bits and then cast it to byte, you will always get a 0. So yes, when you flip the shift, you should receive 60 after sending 60. But for 60 (which is <256) it should be the case without the change

Answer (score 0):

I guess that payload is of type char or unsigned char? 
Then payload[x] << y will shift in the unsigned char size which can obviously not exceed 8 bits. If my assumption is true, your code should read

```
startAngle = (static_cast<unsigned int>payload[0]) << 24) + ((static_cast<unsigned int>payload[1]) << 16) + ((static_cast<unsigned int>payload[2]) << 8) + payload[3];
```

Comment: Your reasoning makes a lot of sense but unfortunatelly the results are the same (60 -> 60, -60 -> 196)

Comment: sry, static_cast<int>(-60) ist wrong for negative numbers. Try unsigned int instead. Edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Sadly, no change. I had to change the brackets a bit to make it work btw. My conversion atm is this:

(static_cast<uint32_t>(payload[0]) << 24) 
                                + (static_cast<uint32_t>(payload[1]) << 16) 
                                + (static_cast<uint32_t>(payload[2]) << 8) 
                                + payload[3];

Comment: Can you provide the results of the single (static_cast<uint32_t>(payload[0]) << 24)? I can hardly believe that it makes no difference at all. Maybe it is helpful for debugging to assign all the shifted components to an uint_32 varaible prior to adding / or-ing them

Comment: (static_cast<uint32_t>(payload[0]) << 24) is received as 0. The same for the bitshifts of payload[1] and payload[2]. Static casting payload[3] without any bitshift to <int> or <uint32_t> both gives 196. now I'm _really_ confused.

Comment: Looking at the sender's side it appears strange to me that the numbers are also shifted to the left. Maybe this is the problem? If the code is intended to decompose it to bytes if should be a right-shift and ANDing with 0xFF. Not sure if JAVA writes 4 bytes to the stream, when serializing a number - so you should make sure that the JAVA also writes BYTES.,,

Comment: I really only receive 4 bytes for the int so each of the port.write() commands on the sending side are transmitting only one byte. I've since updated the `writeIntToSerial()` to cast each of the four write operations' parameters to byte, the results are identical.

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it.

On the sending side I needed to right-shift instead of left-shift:

```
void writeIntToSerial(Serial port, int number) {
  port.write((number >> 24));
  port.write((number >> 16));
  port.write((number >> 8));
  port.write(number);
}
```

And on the receiving side this bitshift-cast sequence does the trick:

```
startAngle = (static_cast<uint32_t>(payload[0]) << 24)
           | (static_cast<uint32_t>(payload[1]) << 16)
           | (static_cast<uint32_t>(payload[2]) << 8) 
           | payload[3];
```